# What's the best way to combine rigidbody markers into a transform?

Tags: python, 3d, linear-algebra, rigid-bodies

I have a motion tracker that gives me the positions of LEDs in space. I know which LED is which. I need to compute the orientation of the rigidbody over time. Right now I build a rotation matrix from three LEDs, by using cross products to make orthogonal basis vectors.

But the code doesn't easily transfer to more than 3 markers. What if I have 6 markers to avoid the danger of less than 3 being in view of the tracker at any time point? I can make a rotation matrix of all combinations of three markers. But how can I use all available markers, which should also help a little bit with measurement noise?

I'm working in python by the way, so numpy examples are appreciated, but not necessary.

Comment: This is the (orthogonal) Procrustes problem; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem for example

Comment: thanks! I didn't know there was an orthogonal version of this, just what I needed. If you add it as an answer I can accept it